# Get a string by number [Python]

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that ends with a number, and I need to find one by a given number.

```py
strings = ["..1", "..2" , "..6", "..16","..26"]
tosearch = 6
for mystr in strings:
    if tosearch in mystr:
        print("FIND!")
```

But if I search with "6" I will find 3 strings (.. 6,.. 16,.. 26)
How can I find a string by exactly the given number (if *tosearch* is 26 I just get ".. 26")

Comment: Strip all `.`s, convert to `int`  then compare with `==` operator.

Comment: i've add point for the exemple in my string before the number it can be any char

Comment: @JoevinFerret, how about `".-2^6.0"` ? does it match?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish your search is to alter the search string:

```
strings = ["..1", "..2" , "..6", "..16","..26"]
tosearch = 6
tosearch = '..{}'.format(tosearch)  # ==> '..6'
for mystr in strings:
    ...
```

Comment: Oh yes i didn't think about this way ! it could work thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) methods returns `True` if all characters in the string are digits, Otherwise, It returns `False`.
[split()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.split) method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.

**Ex.**

```
strings = ["..1", "..2" , "..6", "..16","..26"]
tosearch = 6
for mystr in strings:
    elm = [int(x) for x in mystr.split(".") if x.isdigit()][0]
    if elm == tosearch:
        print("FIND!")
```

**O/P:**

```
FIND!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
strings = ["..1", "..2" , "..6", "..16","..26"]
pattern=re.compile(r"\d+")
stringnumbers = [int(pattern.findall(i)[0]) for i in strings]
tosearch = 6
if tosearch in stringnumbers:
    print("FIND!")
```

---

```
strings = ["..1", "..2" , "..6", "..6","..16","..26"]
nstr =[int(s.replace('.','')) for s in strings]
tosearch = 6
for mystr in nstr:
if tosearch == mystr: 
    print("FIND!")
    break
```

Output:

```
FIND!
```